# SCM Provider not available - Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, maven-3

I was trying to materialize apache Camel project in my eclipse environment. I'm using Maven 3 with Eclipse Galileo and I'm using m2Eclipse plugin.

I'm consistently getting below error message. Is this because my Eclipse lacks the SVN plugin to download from SVN repository or there is some problem with maven repository configured for Apache Camel?

```
3/11/11 9:58:10 PM GMT+05:30: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.6.0/camel-core-2.6.0.pom
3/11/11 9:58:10 PM GMT+05:30: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.6.0/camel-core-2.6.0.pom
3/11/11 9:58:13 PM GMT+05:30: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/camel-parent/2.6.0/camel-parent-2.6.0.pom
3/11/11 9:58:14 PM GMT+05:30: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/camel-parent/2.6.0/camel-parent-2.6.0.pom
3/11/11 9:58:16 PM GMT+05:30: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/camel/2.6.0/camel-2.6.0.pom
3/11/11 9:58:17 PM GMT+05:30: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/camel/2.6.0/camel-2.6.0.pom
3/11/11 9:58:18 PM GMT+05:30: camel-core
3/11/11 9:58:18 PM GMT+05:30: Connection: scm:svn:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/tags/camel-2.6.0
3/11/11 9:58:18 PM GMT+05:30:        dev: scm:svn:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/tags/camel-2.6.0
3/11/11 9:58:18 PM GMT+05:30:        url: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/camel/tags/camel-2.6.0
3/11/11 9:58:18 PM GMT+05:30:        tag: HEAD
3/11/11 9:58:18 PM GMT+05:30: SCM provider is not available for scm:svn:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/tags/camel-2.6.0
3/11/11 9:58:18 PM GMT+05:30: No Maven projects to import
3/11/11 9:58:18 PM GMT+05:30: Project import completed 0 sec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your configuration is not complete, take a look at [this post](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/m2Eclipse-td125234.html).
Maybe you're missing a Subversion plugin.

Comment: Yes. I was missing one of the Maven Extra's needed for m2Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add my existing project in Eclipse Workspace folder by doing following steps.

1. Make sure your project folder (XYZ) is present in your Eclipse Workspace folder. E.g. C:/Eclipse/Workspace/XYZ
2. Go to File -> New -> Project
3. Select General -> Project and click Next
4. A New Project window should appear now
5. Give your project name as your existing project name (e.g. XYZ)
6. Keep 'Use Default Location' checked (No changes)
7. Click on Finish button
8. Now you should see the XYZ project opened in Project Explorer with all project files shown under it.